# error in importing deeplearning4j jar files

Tags: java, maven

```
import org.deeplearning4j.models.embeddings.loader.WordVectorSerializer;
import org.deeplearning4j.models.word2vec.Word2Vec;
import org.deeplearning4j.text.sentenceiterator.BasicLineIterator;
import org.deeplearning4j.text.sentenceiterator.SentenceIterator;
import org.deeplearning4j.text.tokenization.tokenizer.preprocessor.CommonPreprocessor;
import org.deeplearning4j.text.tokenization.tokenizerfactory.DefaultTokenizerFactory;
import org.deeplearning4j.text.tokenization.tokenizerfactory.TokenizerFactory;
import org.deeplearning4j.ui.UiServer;
```

I have issue in importing these files in my program. I have included the jar file deeplearning4j-core-0.4-rc3.8.
Can anyone help how this issue can be resolved?

This error is occuring

Error:(4, 51) java: package org.deeplearning4j.models.embeddings.loader does not exist
Error:(5, 42) java: package org.deeplearning4j.models.word2vec does not exist
Error:(6, 48) java: package org.deeplearning4j.text.sentenceiterator does not exist
Error:(7, 48) java: package org.deeplearning4j.text.sentenceiterator does not exist
Error:(8, 67) java: package org.deeplearning4j.text.tokenization.tokenizer.preprocessor does not exist
Error:(9, 61) java: package org.deeplearning4j.text.tokenization.tokenizerfactory does not exist
Error:(10, 61) java: package org.deeplearning4j.text.tokenization.tokenizerfactory does not exist
Error:(11, 29) java: package org.deeplearning4j.ui does not exist

Comment: can you provide full stack trace of your exception?